# What HTTP headers are required to refresh a page on back button

Tags: http, browser

I'm trying to get a page to refresh when navigated to from the back button.  From what I understand after reading around a bit I should just need to mark the page as uncacheable but I can't get any browsers to refresh the page.  These are the headers I've currently got:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Length:1832
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Mon, 07 Jun 2010 14:05:39 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:Microsoft-IIS/7.5
Vary:Accept-Encoding
Via:1.1 smoothwall:800 (squid/2.7.STABLE6)
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-AspNetMvc-Version:2.0
X-Cache:MISS from smoothwall
X-Powered-By:ASP.NET
```

Why would the browser pull this page from it's browser history and not refresh it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out.  This is what I found to work:

```
Cache-Control:no-cache, no-store
Connection:Close
Content-Length:7683
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Wed, 09 Jun 2010 03:37:38 GMT
Expires:-1
Pragma:no-cache
Server:ASP.NET Development Server/9.0.0.0
X-AspNet-Version:2.0.50727
X-AspNetMvc-Version:2.0
```

achieved with the following ASP.NET code:

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.Cache.SetAllowResponseInBrowserHistory(false);
Response.Cache.SetMaxAge(new TimeSpan(0));
Response.Cache.SetNoStore();
Response.Cache.SetExpires(new DateTime(1940, 1, 1));
```

Comment: This is not true, with this code a page expired warning will be shown. You said, you wanted the page to be refreshed.

Comment: Really?  Which browsers do that?  We've been using this code for sometime now and it seems to be working exactly as we want - ie: on back button the page is re-requested from the server, rather than coming from cache.  What exactly do you mean by page expired warning - is this something the user would?